# is there a link between dstream.checkpoint(checkpointInterval) and spark.streaming.receiver.writeAheadLog.enable

Tags: spark-streaming

As per the spark streaming documentation, dstream which are queued but not processed will be written to checkpoint directory after every checkpointInterval.

but at the same time there is a configuration spark.streaming.receiver.writeAheadLog.enable = true 
which as per the spark documentation "all the data received from a receiver gets written into a write ahead log in the configuration checkpoint directory"

what is the difference in each of the options given by spark?

Answer (score 0):

Metadata checkpointing - Incomplete batches - Batches whose jobs are queued but have not completed yet. This saves the metadata about the batches that are queued not completed yet and will not store the actual data received by the receiver.

On the other hand, if enabled writeAheadLogs will store the actual data thats received by the receiver.

Answer (score 0):

read again the documentation on https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/streaming-programming-guide.html

"For stateful transformations that require RDD checkpointing, the default interval is a multiple of the batch interval that is at least 10 seconds. It can be set by using dstream.checkpoint(checkpointInterval). Typically, a checkpoint interval of 5 - 10 sliding intervals of a DStream is a good setting to try."

So dstream.checkpoint(checkpointInterval) works for stateful dstreams whereas  writeahead logs will work for all dstreams and it is being set at sparkcontext level.

Now based upon above 2 more Queries
1) If the writeahead logs are enabled then is the dstream.checkpoint(checkpointInterval) statement has any significance?
2) what is link of checkpointinterval with Sliding interval as mentioned in doc

"Typically, a checkpoint interval of 5 - 10 sliding intervals of a DStream is a good setting to try."